# How to enable drag status bar from lock screen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, notification-bar

I have Hisense AD686G running on Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich. I can't pull the status bar down in any type of lock screen (slide, pattern, PIN, etc).

I know almost all ICS phones out there have this feature, strangely my phone doesn't.

How do I enable the status bar dragging on the lock screen?

Comment: Depends on the phone/firmware. If the manufacturer locked it, you can't do anything, but downloading another lock screen from the play store may be viable for this.

Comment: did you use any pattern or pin or password lock on your mobile

Comment: @RossC My phone have very limited resources so I cant use third party apps. Isn't there anything else I can do?

Comment: @iDev no I use slide locking.

Comment: @Nur Try rebooting your phone, or if all else fails...the dreaded "battery pull".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any setting is available for notification bar dragging, but the notification dragging bar is enabled/working only on screen lock made by slide. Other than this, it won't work like PIN, pattern, password, etc.

If you want working notification bar, go to Settings -> Security -> Screen Security -> Screen Lock -> change to slide.

Comment: I use slide lock option, but still I can drag status bar, do I need to modify some system files? If it is, can you point me a link of tutorial that tell me what to edit? Since I believe modifying system files is considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Nur Try rebooting your phone, or if all else fails...the dreaded "battery pull".